# How beego(Go App Framework) will reload the application if there is any change in the conf file?

Tags: go, reload, beego

I have developed the application using Golang Beego framework(http://beego.me/) and it is running in the production.

Suppose I edit the configuration file which is conf/app.conf, how can my app will be reloaded with restarting/rebuilding the application?

I tried to run the application using 'bee run' command but still no success in automatic reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run the application with command `bee run` and it supports config file like [this](https://github.com/beego/bee/blob/master/bee.json).
`bee` command watch file change default by file extension. You can see from the source code 
[`var watchExts = []string{".go"}`](https://github.com/beego/bee/blob/master/watch.go#L241). It means `bee` will watch the file with extension `.go`, so if `.go` file change it will auto restarting.

If you want `bee` command to watch the `conf/app.conf` file, you need to make a file `bee.json` at your app directory and the content should like this:

```
{
    "version": 0,
    "gopm": {
        "enable": false,
        "install": false
    },
    "go_install": false,
    "watch_ext": [.conf],
    "dir_structure": {
        "watch_all": false,
        "controllers": "",
        "models": "",
        "others": []
    },
    "cmd_args": [],
    "envs": [],
    "database": {
        "driver": "mysql"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gin](https://github.com/codegangsta/gin), it's really easy to set up:

> gin is a simple command line utility for live-reloading Go web applications. Just run gin in your app directory and your web app will be served with gin as a proxy. gin will automatically recompile your code when it detects a change. Your app will be restarted the next time it receives an HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
Will it rebuild the application automatically?